# Async functions in coffeescript

Tags: function, asynchronous, web, coffeescript

I'm trying to have a function be executed asynchronously like the following code block:

```
asyncSearch = (e) ->
    await search(e)

$("#main-search").on("input", (e) ->
    clearTimeout(delayTimer)
    delayTimer = setTimeout( ->
        asyncSearch(e)
    , 100)
)

#Method for searching

search = (input) ->
    new Promise (resolve) ->
        loadedAlbums = 40
        toggleAlbum(sibling: undefined)
        //more code
        ....
```

This, however, isn't compiling like I'd expect it to. Instead it's compiling to:

```
 asyncSearch = function(e) {
  return await(search(e));
};

$("#main-search").on("input", function(e) {
  clearTimeout(delayTimer);
  return delayTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    return asyncSearch(e);
  }, 100);
});

search = function(input) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    var album, doSearch, inputValues, k, l, len, m, rawInput, ref, tempAlbums;
    loadedAlbums = 40;
    //more code
    ...
```

The error I'm then getting is understandably a ReferenceError where "await" isn't defined.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could be a coffeescript version problem, I was able to replicate the issue in this fiddle, but it works when I change it to coffeescript 2. https://jsfiddle.net/xk7nh4en/